# form action redirect from JS (reCaptcha)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a submit form, after checking the captcha v3, I need to send the form with the same values. how to do this after receiving the token from the captcha?

With the code below, either a human or a bot outputs to the browser console, but does not redirect to the desired page

```
.then(result => {
                        if (result['om_score'] >= 0.5) {
                            console.log('Human')
                        } else {
                            console.log('Bot')
                        }
                     });
```

If i use `window.location = "mail.php";` insted of `console.log` it send empty request

My goal is that the redirect would be to the `<from>` action with the entered values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JS to submit the form. Suppose you have the following `form`:

```
<form id="myform" action="mail.php" method="post">
    ....
</form>
```

You can use JS to submit it:

```
....
.then(result => {
    if (result['om_score'] >= 0.5) {
        console.log('Human')
        document.getElementById("myform").submit();
    } else {
        console.log('Bot')
    }
});
```

As a side note, you shouldn't be checking the Captcha client-side because it can easily be spoofed.